# Recover photos that got deleted when device switched off?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-recovery, photos, moto-x

I have a Moto X Pure running Android 6.0. I have a lot of pictures saved on it. I was recently taking pictures and the device ran out of battery and switched off. When I got home and turned it back on, I couldn't locate the last 30 or so photos that I took when the battery was running low. The videos that I took during this same time show a file size of 0kB and are not openable. However, all the older photos - even the ones I took earlier on the same day - are completely unaffected. I am wondering what could have caused this? Is there a way to recover the photos without having to root the device (most file recovery software that Google searches showed up need the device to be rooted to access internal memory)? I have around 1 GB of free space and I've never received a low disk space notification, nor did I get any other error when taking these pictures. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your device to PC/Laptop whatever you have and use one of the data recovery tool like recuva*, easeus, etc. So, download [easeus](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/mobile-device-recovery/android-file-recovery-tool.htm) on your PC and connect your phone then select your device to scan for picture or videos or whatever you like. Good thing is that you **don't need the rooted device** to do that.
*Recuva cannot act on an Android device's storage, if device has been set to MTP. But if your files were on MicroSD cards you can use recuva to scan them.(thanks to  Death Mask Salesman)